# Return objects from a map function if true

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to return object(s) from a map function only if documents are checked. Here is the structure of my state.

```
    {
        type: ListOfTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListOfTypes.length)],
        name: ListOfNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListOfNames.length)],
        id: nanoid(),
        channels: [
            {
                id: nanoid(),
                Name: ListOfChannels[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListOfChannels.length)],
                Files: [
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },],
            },
            {
                id: nanoid(),
                Name: ListOfChannels[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListOfChannels.length)],
                Files: [
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: nanoid(),
                Name: ListOfChannels[Math.floor(Math.random() * ListOfChannels.length)],
                Files: [
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                    { folder: "Folder", id: nanoid(), documents: [{ doc: "WordDoc1.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc2.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc3.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }, { doc: "WordDoc4.doc", isChecked: false, id: nanoid() }] },
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried to map through the state array but I got an object with un necessary arrays using this.

```
const handleMoveAll = () => {

    const CheckedDocuments = List.map( (connection: any) => (connection.id == connectionId) &&
        connection.channels.map( (channel: any) => (channel.id == channelId) &&
            channel.Files.map( (file: any) =>
                file.documents.map( (doc: any) => doc.isChecked && 
                doc
                ))

        )
    )

    console.log(CheckedDocuments)
}
```

Is there a better way to loop through the Files array checking for checked documents and returning   them in a single array?

Comment: instead of map, you can use filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You can use `flatMap` to both `map` and `filter` in same function. In case the condition is true return `[ obj ]` otherwise return `[]` . @oakar `filter` just return the mapped item, not possible to manipulate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HagaiHarari & @oakar.

```
const handleMoveAll = () => {

        const CheckedDocuments = List.flatMap((connection: any) => (connection.id == connectionId) ?
            connection.channels.flatMap((channel: any) => (channel.id == channelId) ?
                channel.Files.flatMap( (file: any) =>
                    file.documents.filter( (doc: any) => { if(doc.isChecked) return doc }
                    ))
                : []
            )
            : []
        )

        console.log(CheckedDocuments)
    }
```